# Antlr4 - Match rule only if a previous rule matched

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have a parser laid out similarly to (though not exactly like) this:

```
compilationUnit: statement* EOF;
methodBody:      statement*;
ifBlock:         IF '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}' ;
statement:       methodBody | ifBlock | returnStatement | ... ;
```

This parser works fine, and I can use it. However, it has the flaw that `returnStatement` will parse even if it's not in a method body. Ideally, I would be able to set it up such that `returnStatement` will only match in the `statement` rule if one of its parents down the line was `methodBody`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate the statements that appear inside the methodBody from the ones that appear outside of that scope. Ideally you will have two different productions. Something like this:

```
compilationUnit: member* EOF;
member:          method | class | ... ;
method:          methodName  '(' parameters ')' '{' methodBody '}' ;
methodBody:      statement*;
statement:       methodBody | ifBlock | returnStatement | ... ;
ifBlock:         IF '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}' ;
```

Comment: if `methodBody:      statement*;` then do you need `tatement:       methodBody | ifBlock | returnStatement | ... ;` or would `statement:       ifBlock | returnStatement | ... ;` do the same thing?

Comment: The problem is that I want loose code to be legal, so I can't do that. I could have a special type of `methodStatement` rule, but then I would also need to create two `ifBlock` rules for in versus out of a function, and eventually I'm just duplicating half of my grammar.

Comment: What about `methodBody:      (statement | returnStatement)*;` and then remove `returnStatement` from the `statement` production

Comment: I thought of that too at first, until I went to start adding the `ifBlock` rule. `returnStatement` needs to be accessible from `ifBlock` if a parent down the line is `methodBody`.

Comment: Like I said in my original comment, you have to differentiate the types of statements with their own productions. Even if you have to duplicate some of them. Take a look as this JS grammar https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/javascript/JavaScriptParser.g4

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve this problem at the wrong level. It shouldn't be handled at the grammar level, but in the following semantic phase (which is used to find logical/semantic errors, instead of syntax errors, what your parser is dealing with). You can see the same approach in the [C grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4#L456). The `statement` rule references the `jumpStatement` rule, which in turn matches (among others) the return statement.

Handling such semantic errors also allows for better error messages. Instead of "no viable alt" you can print an error that says "return only allowed in a function body" or similar. To do that examine the generated parse tree, search for return statements and check the parent context(s) of that sub tree to know if it is valid or not.